# Problemas al usar campo booleano en django

Tags: python, django

tengo una duda, lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de usar Boolean y me da muchos errores. Intento cambiar estatus=CharField y ahi no hay errores, sólo es cuando lo paso a Boolean Mil gracias :)
Aquí el código:

**models.py**

```
   codigo=models.IntegerField()
   estatus = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=255)

   def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.codigo}: {self.estatus} {self.descripcion}'
```

**admin.py**

```
    search_fields = ('codigo','estatus','descripcion',)
    list_display = ('codigo','estatus','descripcion')
    
    admin.site.register(Parte, ParteAdmin)
```

y por último me aparece este extraño error:

```
 File "C:\Users\Itzel\trabajo\factus\dev\taller_mecanico\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
   return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo boolean: «Pendiente»
```

Actualización

Gracias al usuario que contestó, aparece el checkbox, sólo que al guardar cambios en la base de datos me aparece el siguiente error, colocaré la imagen para ilustrar esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Refrescaste los cambios en la base de datos con los respectivos comandos **makemigrations** y **migrate**?

Comment: cuando uso migrate me aparece el siguiente error: django.db.utils.DataError: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo boolean: «Pendiente»

Comment: Importante que elimines las imagenes agrega simplemnte el texto principal del error y con eso basta.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está relacionado con la transicción del tipo `CharField` a `BooleanField`. La solución sencilla es eliminar todos los registros que tenias guardados con el esquema anterior (con Charfield), esto debido a que al momento de intentar hacer el cambio a `BooleanField`, estos registros con valores de tipo **char** no pueden ser convertidos a  un valor **booleano**, resultando en el error que te aparece.

Comment: Eliminar los registros existentes no siempre es un opción viable hay casos en que es data de producción por tanto puedes utilizar un comando o una migración para convertir esos datos de alguna manera a su respectivo equivalente.